# Error 404 while opening site, httpd.conf?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver, httpd.conf

I have a php application that I needed to open on a local web server. I'm running Windows 7 on my VM. Have installed php 7.3.6, mysql, apache 2.4.

1. After some configuration trying to open my "application" with "localhost/application".
2. Getting "Internal error 500".
3. In Apache logs can see "C:/WebData/application/.htaccess: Invalid command 'order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"
4. In .htaccess I have:

```
order deny,allow
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

5. Change first line into "Require all granted"
6. Trying to open "localhost/application"
7. Getting the error "404 URL /index.php" not found
8. Trying to open "localhost/application/index.php"
9. Forwarding to "localhost/ru/main"
10. Getting another error "404 URL .." not found

Also after each request I see that `htaccess` is changing back into its initial state with "order deny,allow".

Is there something wrong with `httpd.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't run `mod_access_compat`, which means `Order` is not available, as it's deprecated in Apache 2.4 (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html)

Now, the reason why your `.htaccess` files get overwritten probably lies in the PHP code you're running. Some applications try to auto-configure themselves and will write their own `.htaccess` file to make sure they run properly.

The fact this particular app tries to write deprecated commands without checking if the version of `Apache` you are running is capable of handling them is concerning and probably means it's outdated.

Do a global search on the application files and look for that `Order deny, allow` rule, I'm pretty sure you'll find the culprit.

If you can run a newer version of that code, do so, and if not, and if patching it manually is an option, change it to `Require all granted`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The problem was really caused by automatic generation of .htaccess by index.php of the application. After I changed auto-config to ""require all granted" it all worked!

You can't even imagine how grateful am I! Wish you good luck in everything you do!